# Backtrack after running Johnson algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, bellman-ford

I have a question which I was asked in some past exams at my school and I can't find an answer to it.

> Is it possible knowing the final matrix after running the [*Johnson Algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) on a graph, to know if it previously had negative cycles or not? Why?

---

### Johnson Algorithm

Johnson's Algorithm is a technique that is able to compute shortest paths on graphs. Which is able to handle negative weights on edges, as long as there does not exist a cycle with negative weight.

The algorithm consists of (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm)):

- First, a new node `q` is added to the graph, connected by zero-weight edges to each of the other nodes.
- Second, the *Bellman–Ford* algorithm is used, starting from the new vertex `q`, to find for each vertex `v` the minimum weight `h(v)` of a path from `q` to `v`. If this step detects a negative cycle, the algorithm is terminated.
- Next the edges of the original graph are reweighted using the values computed by the *Bellman–Ford* algorithm: an edge from `u` to `v`, having length `w(u, v)`, is given the new length `w(u,v) + h(u) − h(v)`.
- Finally, `q` is removed, and *Dijkstra's* algorithm is used to find the shortest paths from each node `s` to every other vertex in the reweighted graph.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question a bit more? Maybe make an example. That way your question reaches more people, is easier to understand, self-contained and helps more people finding your question.

Comment: Did you mean to say "if it previously had negative _edges_" instead of "if it previously had negative cycles"?   Because Johnson's algorithm aborts if there are negative cycles.

Comment: Yes, my bad, negative edges. I don't know how to elaborate more because this is how i found the question, and I'm confused too.

Comment: "knowing the final matrix" - you mean knowing the distances matrix?

Comment: Do you agree with @ShaharA's suggestion or does "final matrix" refer to the updated non-negative edge weights? If the latter then no you can't tell, because running Johnson on a graph with non-negative weights leaves them unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, which should have been as follows:

> Is it possible knowing the final pair-wise distances matrix after running the Johnson Algorithm on a graph, to know if it originally had any **negative-weight edges** or not? Why?

As others commented here, we must first assume the graph has no negative weight cycles, since otherwise the Johnson algorithm halts and returns False (due to the internal Bellman-Form detection of negative weight cycles).

The answer then is that if any negative weight edge e = (u, v) exists in the graph, then the shortest weighted distance between u --> v cannot be > 0 (since at the worst case you can travel the negative edge e between those vertices).

[image]

Therefore, at least one of the edges had negative weight in the original graph iff any value in the final pair-wise distances is < 0

Answer (score 0):

If the question is supposed to be interpreted as:

> Is it possible, knowing the **updated non-negative edge weights** after running the Johnson Algorithm on a graph, to know if it originally had any **negative-weight edges** or not? Why?

Then no, you can't tell.

Running the Johnson algorithm on a graph that has only non-negative edge weights will leave the weights unchanged. This is because all of the shortest distances `q -> v` will be 0. Therefore, given the edge weights after running Johnson, the initial weights could have been exactly the same.